# Prove that $a+b^2+c^3+d^4 \ge \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^3}+\frac{1}{d^4}$

Tags: inequality

> If $0 < a \le b \le c \le d$ and $abcd = 1$ prove that $$a+b^2+c^3+d^4 \ge \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^3}+\frac{1}{d^4}$$

I first thought of multiplying both sides with $\big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^3}+\frac{1}{d^4}\big)$

Then by applying C-S inequality in the LHS the inequality would be $$16 \ge \Big(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^3}+\frac{1}{d^4}\Big)^2$$

But if $(a,b,c,d)=(\frac14,1,1,4)$ the inequality does not hold true.

Comment: You can assume them to be $x,y..z$ and then use $AM>=HM$

Comment: the RHS should have been $\frac{4}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^3}+\frac{1}{d^4}}$

Comment: this is from Michael Rozenberg it is not so simple

Comment: i have proved it by BW but this proof is ugly